# Change NumberDecimalSeparator

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there any way to change `NumberDecimalSeparator` in current culture?

This code doesn't change anything...
I write it in App.xaml.cs in `InitializeLanguage()` function..

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

*I can't think of a good reason why you'd want to do that.  It is more than likely to confuse your users since they are used to seeing numbers formatted according to the rules of their own culture.*

If you really do have a compelling case for doing this, though, why not find a culture with the format that you want to apply, and supply that culture as an argument to your string conversion code to achieve the same result?

Comment: It's easy. A lot of people in my country use '.' in apps instead of default ','.

Comment: If you use binding to double directly, conversion is default. And so this acces would be much easier. It is just more simple to change/add just one line of code, then to rewriting every conversion in whole app.